# how to install ubuntu 12.0 on MacOS with multi-boot menu

Tags: mac, unix

Hey guys I need to install ubuntu on my Macbook but I have not got the ideas how to separate hdd disk in right order (size and disk formats and of course utilities). At now MacOS 's installed correct. My final goal - installed correct two OS with multi-boot (mac is primary one) Please give some correct steps how must i do it. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an empty partition with Disk Utility under OS X, shrinking the existing OS X partition. It shouldn't destroy data, but make a backup (just in case).
2. Boot Ubuntu using Live CD or Live USB.
3. Run the installer, and choose to manually select the partitions. Choose the empty partition as the root mount point (`/`) and make sure Ubuntu doesn't touch any other partition. The installer should format the partition as ext4 or ext3. Make Ubuntu install the GRUB bootloader (just leave the default settings).
4. You'll need an EFI boot loader. rEFIt is no longer mantained; **[rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)** did a good work with my installation. You can install it from OS X very easily.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complex but the essential steps are:

- You'll need install the refit boot-manager (in order to sync between the Mac EFI and Ubuntu MBR partition table)
- Then in diskutil shrink your current (or any partition) to make room for ubuntu
- Install Ubuntu
- Reboot and use Refit to fix the partition table

There are more steps (like drivers and stuff), the above is just the essential rundown.  Details are in [this article](http://lifehacker.com/5934942/how-to-dual-boot-linux-on-your-mac-and-take-back-your-powerhouse-apple-hardware).

Comment: The-Dood, thank you for your answer. So previously i have had experience in using rEfit and have got the negative opinion based on:                             - time of booting before selecting OS(I mean reFit OSes selecting screen) - unstable system work - two operation systems

Comment: Well, your choce.  I have refit running on multiple machines without problem.  And since your problem (making partitions that require sync of MBR and EFI partition tables) is something refit does well, I'll be curious to see if you'll find other ways to do that.